# How to verify that the current text in specific element is showed on page using Selenium IDE?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide

I have a question which can not solve.

Can everyone tell me how to locate the current element showed next

```
<td style="width: 250; text-align:right" class="stData"> March 14 2014, 00:00 </td>
```

that contains exactly the "March 14 2014, 00:00"  text?

Answer (score 0):

You may try a powerful java package [`jsoup`](http://jsoup.org/). Some guides are [`here`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/).

Answer (score 0):

Use verifyText, verifyNotText methods to verify text is presence with Selenium IDE.

**verifyText(locator, pattern)**

```
Arguments:

    locator - an element locator

Returns:
    the text of the element

Gets the text of an element. This works for any element that contains text. This command uses either the textContent (Mozilla-like browsers) or the innerText (IE-like browsers) of the element, which is the rendered text shown to the user.
```

**verifyNotText(locator, pattern)**

```
Arguments:

    locator - an element locator

Returns:
    the text of the element

Gets the text of an element. This works for any element that contains text. This command uses either the textContent (Mozilla-like browsers) or the innerText (IE-like browsers) of the element, which is the rendered text shown to the user.
```